# Add additional matching between two arrays to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Here's what I want to achieve. I've 2 arrays, one for artists and one for releases. I am currently matching "ArtistID" to each to display "Releases by this artists" on my SingleArtist page. However I want to take it a step further and add another identifier if the release features them. Example : release A has artist A, but a remixer B. Is there a way to do it within by doing more filtering on the arrays(s)? Not sure how to go about it. Thanks.

example from releases.json

```
{
"id": 9,
"artistID": "SU",
"featuredartist": "ES, FG",
"imageURL": "../images/releases/dulcie.jpg",
"title": "Dulcie Caught a Cricket",
"description": "Released 2020",
"artist": "Sumsuch",
"buy": "https://www.beatport.com/release/we-choose/1916121",
"stream": "https://open.spotify.com/album/4cutoknbgciTGGpAYSZXfK?si=gsNvR6ytTN6KdrPORfSLOg"
},
```

example from artists.json (the second object is a remixer 'id:0' who is featured on 'id:3' and would like that to display under the "ES" releases

```
{
"id": 3,
"artistID": "SU",
"imageURL": "./images/sumsuch.jpg",
"singleimageURL": "../images/artists/sumsuch.jpg",
"name": "SUMSUCH",
"bio": "Will Sumsuch has been a musician, producer and DJ",
"soundcloud": "sumsuch"
},

{
"id": 0,
"artistID": "ES",
"imageURL": "./images/artists/ericblue.jpg",
"singleimageURL": "../images/artists/ericblue.jpg",
"name": "ERIC SHANS",
"bio": "A producer and DJ residing in Brooklyn, NY,
},
```

code for singleartist.js (abbreviated)

```
 function SingleArtist() {
  const { id } = useParams() //finds single artist from array & matches ID
  const artist = artists.find((a) => a.id === +id)
  //finds ArtistID from Artists then matches any item that has the same value from the Releases array
  const releaseList = releases.filter((b) => b.artistID === artist.artistID)
  const { singleimageURL, name, soundcloud, bio } = artist

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div className="artist-container">
        <div className='item'>
          <div className='image'>
            <img className='artist' src={singleimageURL} alt={name} />
          </div>
          <div className="description">
            <p className='name'>
              {name}
            </p>
            <p className='bio'>
              {bio}
            </p>
          </div>
          <a href={'https://soundcloud.com/' + soundcloud} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
            Listen to {name}'s Soundcloud
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span>
        <Link className='link-back' to="/artists"> Back To Artists</Link>
      </span>

      <div className="matches">
        <h4> Releases by {name} </h4>
        {releaseList.map(release => {
          const { imageURL, name, id, buy } = release;
          return (
            <div className="item" key={id}>
              <a href={buy} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                <img className="image" src={imageURL} alt={name} />
              </a>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where is the data being stored that shows `featured_artists`? In other words, where in your data is it telling you that artist with `id:0` was featured in a release by artist with `id:3`?

Comment: @JBrown I actually added that to the releases.json - sorry meant to put it.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your question, you simply want to find a list of releases that an artist is featured in on the single artist page. This line should do the trick:

```js
let releases = [{
"id": 9,
"artistID": "SU",
"featuredartist": "ES, FG",
},{
"id": 3,
"artistID": "ED",
"featuredartist": "SU, FG",
}]

const featuredList = releases.filter(release => release.featuredartist.split(", ").includes("SU"));

console.log(featuredList);
```

You can insert this directly below the line where you set `releaseList`. It is basically the same idea. This line filters the releases again, and then splits the `featuredartists` string into an array of strings. Then, if the array includes the artist's id, you return it.

Comment: thank you but i am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: My apologies. I used `featuredartists` instead of `featuredartist`. Should work now.

Comment: thanks a lot, i actually caught that and used featuredartist but no luck, same result. When I do  console.log(releases.featuredartists) it's coming up as undefined.

Comment: `releases.featuredartists` is undefined 1) because it's still spelled wrong and 2) because `releases` is an array of objects. Try logging `release.featuredartist` while inside the filter and see if it gives you a string.

Comment: thanks I changed it in the JSON to match it so the spelling's correct. I tried logging release.featuredartists in the filter but it's still coming up undefined. Must be something I am doing wrong. Will keep trying, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! I added a code snippet above that is working. Maybe it can help you debug.